# How to validate props for functional component declared inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

How to fix props validation for functional component that declared inside functional component?

For my example there is need to validate rowData, style props

```
function renderRow({ rowData, style })
```

```
function App({ data, user }) {

// rowData is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types
// style is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types

  function renderRow({ rowData, style }) { 
     /* Row require props from function params and vars from functional component scope*/    
     return (
      <Row
        user={user}
        rowData={rowData}
        style={style}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <Table
      data={data}
      renderRow={renderRow}
    />
  )
}
```

I know it doesn't make sense, but I have no idea why it asks to validate props
[image]

Comment: If `renderRow` is a react component then it should be named correctly, i.e. `RenderRow`. Have you tried `renderRow.propTypes = { /* define the PropTypes */ };`? Are you sure `renderRow` is *actually* intended to be a component, versus a utility function that returns JSX?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? I'm pretty sure it won't trigger a validation, it doesn't make sense. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DrewReese I think a function that returns JSX is component

Comment: `const renderItem = (item, count, index) => <div>Hi</div>;` is a function that returns JSX but isn't a react component. Many react component solutions that deal with rendering lists/tabular data/etc.. tend to utilize a "renderItem/renderRow" function.

Comment: Just try `renderRow={({ rowData, style }) => {...}}` without declaring a function in body

Comment: @DennisVash It depends on props from functional component, so the simplest solution to declare it in inside function component. I'll do that If don't find solution for eslint

Comment: Try making **reproducible example** like asked for. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj

Comment: @DennisVash Codesandbox doesn't support custom eslint config

Comment: Of course it does, it supported.

Comment: I've tried to setup eslint config for codesandbox project, it din't work. And there is an issue about it https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1933